# Styling Action Bar(Background Color) Android

Tags: android

I want to make the action bar red and it is not working. It launches the app and then immediately says "Unfortunately, Action Bar has stopped" and I can see the app real quick and it is read.  I looked for hours and nothing has come up on the internet. Can someone please provide help, since I am new to coding?

**logcat**

```
      05-29 01:04:39.051
 21993-21993funnestgames.actionbarActivityThread:PauseGC
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not     
        found:dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**styl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#F00</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="funnestgames.actionbar" >

<application
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have fixed the log layout problem for you. Hopefully there is enough information for someone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below

```
ActionBar action_bar = getActionBar();
action_bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
```

Change your style from

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: I tried that it did not work. ill try again. in the java class right? in "onCreateOptionsMenu"?

Comment: Ok. That works. (YAY) Made everything white. now how do i make the action bar red? Like I said I am new to coding.

Comment: ActionBar action_bar = getActionBar();
action_bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

Comment: use this line in oncreate

Comment: i also posted the logcat in the original question for the problem i was getting when i was trying what the android tutorial on their website said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">Your color you want or drawable</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">Your color you want or drawable</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">Your color you want or drawable</item>
</style>
```

And add this on AppTheme your app:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
```

Or try use [tools](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: are u try use this tools? and copy all style into your styles.xml. remember copy all on res...

Comment: can you share for me your project?

Comment: u can push your project into git. May be [gitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)  and share for me your link of project on gitbucket. U can use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)  is a UI Git.

Comment: or the easiest way is you compress your project and uploaded to  [Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com) and then share link of this file for me

Comment: it is just a new project from android studio with a blank activity. API 4.0

and all i changed was the android manifest and styles.

Comment: oh.... when u change style xml file, do u config AppTheme on AndroidManifest? I just use [this tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), download res folder and replace them to res folder on my project. Then config AppTheme for them on my ANdroidManifest. It's ok with me